# Insert particular rows to others group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in which I want to substract one of the particular row and add into the other groups within the same data frame.

Lets say we have a data like this;

```
import pandas as pd    

raw_data = {'regiment': ['51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st'], 
            'trucks': ['MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150'],
            'drivers': ['MAZ', 'MAZ', 'IVE', 'IVE', 'MAN', 'MAN', 'MERC', 'TATA', 'TATA', 'MAN', 'REN', 'TATA'],


            'counts': [5,5,1,1,0,0,1,0, 1,2,3,4]}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'trucks','drivers','counts'])

 regiment     trucks drivers  counts
0      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
1      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
2      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
3      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
6      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
7      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
8      51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
9      51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
10     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
11     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

and I want to substract the rows with `drivers == MAZ` add into other groups and make a change their `trucks` groups so they match the groups they go into.

The end result that I need is like this

```
regiment     trucks drivers  counts
0      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
1      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
2      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
3      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAZ       5
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAZ       5
6      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
7      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
8      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
9      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
10     51st    ZIS-150     MAZ       5
11     51st    ZIS-150     MAZ       5
12     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
13     51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
14     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
16     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

I started by this

```
df =  df[df['drivers'].str.contains('MAZ',case=True)]
    regiment    trucks drivers  counts
0     51st  MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
1     51st  MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
samples = df[df.drivers.eq('MAZ')].reset_index(drop=True)
(pd.concat([samples.assign(trucks=t)  
                for t in df.trucks.unique()] + [df.drop(samples.index)])
   .sort_values(['trucks'], kind='mergesort')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   regiment     trucks drivers  counts
0      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
1      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       5
2      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
3      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAZ       5
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAZ       5
6      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
7      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
8      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
9      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
10     51st    ZIS-150     MAZ       5
11     51st    ZIS-150     MAZ       5
12     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
13     51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
14     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
15     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. May I ask how you approach the solution, Is there a similar post ? which I couldn't find or some other source?